# "Invalid referrer" shown instead of CAPTCHA on the blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

When I click "more >>" at the bottom of a post summary on the blog, I see this at the bottom:

[image: screenshot]

Occassionally the CAPTCHA shows up properly, but most of the time this error is shown.

Repro'd on WinXP:

- Chrome 13.0.782.107 beta-m
- Chrome 13.0.782.109 beta-m
- IE 8
- FF 5.0

Also repro'd on a BlackBerry browser (can't tell you which version, sorry).

Comment: @Grace Sorry! I get all confused when it doesn't make sense to have my post title consist of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We saw it today and made the remark to Rebecca Chernoff in the chat.

We are highly suspecting the graduation of the blog to be responsible for that behaviour since it was gaming.blogoverflow.com and is now blog.gaming.stackexchange.com

This would explain the "bad referer" thing since ReCaptcha is probably still expecting the old one.

Trying to rewrite the URL with the old domain seems to bring up the UI of ReCaptcha without the actual captcha.

Answer (score 4):

I've updated the settings, so should be good to go.  (Someone comment and confirm it's good please)

Comment: Confirmed, looks good.

Comment: Yep, success here as well, thanks